# Listings: Math Symbol as Line Comment

Tags: listings, pandoc

I'm using pandoc to transform markdown to latex to PDF. Where there's no fitting (simple) solution in MD, I use inline latex.

Since hash / pound (`#`) signs are title markers in MD, I'd like to escape them in listings. The only way I know to do this is to use mathescape, writing `$\#$`. So far, so good, but unfortunately in code which uses the hash as a single line comment marker (e.g. python or sh) will not be colored correctly any longer.

My question: how do I correctly define the maths symbol to start a single line comment? Failing that, iss there another way of escaping the hash symbol in the listing which works?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually found a workaround right after posting. Adding `$$` in front of the leading hash will change nothing in latex, but everything in MD (because it's only a title if the line starts with a hash)... I'm still interested in an actual answer to the question, but in case anyone finds this, it may be usesful.

Comment: Your main concern is that the editor recognizes `#` as a title marker and therefore formats it differently within the code. The output, however, remains completely fine. So escaping it is a way to circumvent the visual discomfort. Correct?

Comment: @Werner: that is correct, so I'm kind of fine with my current workaround. It's mainly curiosity now ;-)